# Sencha Touch : Nested List with one level?

Tags: sencha-touch, nested-lists

I'd like to know if it's possible to show a child leaf on the first level on a nestedlist ?

On the example beside, i'd like to show a page when you select "MY CATEGORY" (the last item) but I have a parent issue if i use the getDetailCard function. the message is :

"'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'parent.attributes.record.data')"

DATA

```
var data = {
text: 'Groceries',
items: [{
    text: 'WATER',
    items: [{
        text: 'Water',
        items: [{
            text: 'Sparkling',
            info : 'THIS TEXT IS SHOWN IN THE CHILD LEAF',
            leaf: true
        },{
            text: 'Still',
            leaf: true
        }]
    },{
        text: 'Coffee',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Espresso',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Redbull',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Coke',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Diet Coke',
        leaf: true
    }]
}],{
    text: 'Fruit',
    items: [{
        text: 'Bananas',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Lemon',
        leaf: true
    }]
},{
    text: 'Snacks',
    items: [{
        text: 'Nuts',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Pretzels',
        leaf: true
    },{
        text: 'Wasabi Peas',
        leaf: true
    }]
},{
    text: 'My Category',
    info : 'TEXT I WANT TO SHOW ON A CHILD LEAF',
    leaf: true
}]
};
```

MODEL & STORE :

```
Ext.regModel('ListItem', {
fields: [

{name: 'text', type: 'string'},
{name: 'info', type: 'string'}

]
});

var store = new Ext.data.TreeStore({
model: 'ListItem',
root: data,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    reader: {
        type: 'tree',
        root: 'items'
    }
}
});
```

Thanks for your help, regards.

Answer (score 0):

The leaf 'TEXT I WANT TO SHOW ON A CHILD LEAF' don't have a parent (actually it's 'parent' is the root element of the tree).